# Why is the initial speech of Gad and R'euven divided into two?

Tags: mattos

In [*Matos*, 32](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9960/showrashi/true):2–4, we have (in loose translation):

> The children of *Gad* and the children of *R'uven* came and said to *Moshe*, to *El'azar* the *kohen*, and to the heads of the congregation as follows:
>
> > *Ataros*, *Divon*, *Ya'zer*, *Nimra*, *Cheshbon*, *El'ale*, *S'vam*, *N'vo*, and *B'on* — the land [whose inhabitants] God struck<sup>[1]</sup> before the Jewish people — is a land for animals<sup>[2]</sup>. And [we] your servants have animals<sup>[2]</sup>.

Then there's a break (a blank "*s'suma*" space in the Torah scroll), and the narrative continues (verse 5):

> And they said:
>
> > If we have found favor in your eyes, the land should be given to [us] your servants for ownership: do not cross us over the Jordan.

What's with the paragraph break and the repeated "And they said"? It seems to be one long speech.

---

I see *ibn Ezra* (in his "long" commentary, the one in "*mikraos g'dolos*" *chumashim*) has a brief explanation, but I don't understand it; an explication of what he says is very welcome, certainly, among answers below. The *Or Hachayim* also has an explanation (that the new "they said" is for their request, whereas the first part is forestalling potential objections), but I don't see how that really explains the need for a new "they said" (or break), so, again, if someone can explain it, that'd be very welcome as an answer.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *Onkelos*. (The *tafsir* of *Rav Saadya Gaon* has "the land God captured" or something like that.)
<sup>[2]</sup> The word used is one that denotes sheep and/or goats, actually. Hey, I said it was a loose translation!

Comment: I saw this year that _Abarbanel_ also says that the second speech is their request whereas the first is to forestall objections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R' Hirsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch)'s [commentary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0910818126) on verse 5 addresses this curiosity:

> This repeated restarting their speech implies a pause, and shows that they themselves were not without suspicion as to how their proposition would be received. They required a pause to pull themselves together to continue bringing their request forward.

Comment: Slightly different angle: they paused, hoping Moshe would volunteer a solution (he didn't). "Well dad you know it's a really long walk to college and a car would be nice ..." Or another tweak -- the pause wasn't in their speech per se, it's the Chumash  telling us they *should have* stopped there, presenting the facts, and let Moshe propose the solution.

Comment: @Shalom, your first idea is similar to how R' Hirsch interprets this sort of pattern in Lavan's conversation with Ya'akov Avinu regarding compensation. Lavan: "I have this religious feeling that you've been quite the good luck charm. (So, tell me you're flattered, and we won't have to get into the crass matter of compensation.)" Ya'akov: <Stares at Lavan silently, thinking "No, I've been quite the good worker!"> Lavan: "OK, what do you want to be paid." http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/mxdfi/devar_torah_vayeitzei_5772_discarding_lavans/

Comment: @IsaacMoses by your second sentence I was picturing XtraNormal bears.

Comment: RSRH's explanation may fit with the _Or Hachayim_'s (mentioned in the question).

Comment: @msh210, Yes. The RSRH's and OHCh's explanations are different, but they could complement each other.

Comment: @IsaacMoses SO AWESOME!

Comment: @Shalom *[CHALLENGE ACCEPTED!](http://youtu.be/a-bte0vUJ6k)*